Eclipse IDE different scrollbar
Until now my (Previous) Eclipse installation had a compact scrollbar that would expand when hovered. Recently I had to reinstall Eclipse and for some reason the Scroll bars no longer contract and it's really annoying. I liked it when the scrollbars were practically invisible. Is there a way to make them expand and contract again or even get rid of them for good? It is almost the exact same, same plugins, same settings.
I looked through settings in search of a setting for this and Google didn't help.

On what OS? Eclipse just uses the native OS scroll bar so this is normally an OS setting.

Windows 11. I haven't replaced or reinstalled my operating system...
